# Subtraction of unsigned values in return statement of a function that return signed type

Tags: c++, c++11, types, sign, unsigned

I've run into code that simplified looks like this

```
__int64 fun(unsigned __int64 x, unsigned __int64 y)
{
    return x - y;
}
```

In Visual Studio it works fine even when y>x and we have proper negative value. But is it a UB or valid situation and all other compilers will handle this also properly?

Comment: `x-y` creates a new value, that is copied as an integer, which is signed.

Comment: The problem with this question is that `__int64` is not a standard type. So "all other compilers" doesn't make much sense in full generality. Can't you reformulate to `std::uint64_t` and `std::int64_t` instead? The issue with that is that the complementing scheme of `__int64` would also be implementation defined.

Comment: To make this even more complicated, different rules apply for the *assigning* to an out of range type to *initialisation* to an out of range type.  Then things changed from C++20. Oh joy!

Comment: @Bathsheba as long as it is an integral type, it is subject to integral conversion rules, which are the same for standard and implementation-defined integral types alike.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is never UB. In the last C++ standard it is always well-defined:

> the result is the unique value of the destination type that is congruent to the source integer modulo *2<sup>N</sup>*, where *N* is the width of the destination type.

In some previous standards, it could have been implementation-defined:

> If the destination type is signed, the value is unchanged if it can be represented in the destination type (and bit-field width); otherwise, the value is implementation-defined.

However, in practice every inplementation does the modulo *2<sup>N</sup>* thing.